# Using Google.Apis.Auth results in a unique exception in .Net project

Tags: c#, .net-core, google-cloud-firestore, google-api

Good day!
I am trying to add Google Authentication to Firestore project.
Used various bundles VS2017, VS2019, .net Core 2.2, 3.1, .net 5.0.
The whole project works fine until any mention of Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc.Controllers (or AspNetCore3) is added.
Once a simple mention is added in the Startup.cs

```
app.UseEndpoints (...);
```

an exception is thrown
*System.TypeLoadException: "Could not load type 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' from assembly 'System.Web, Version = 4.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = b03f5f7f11d50a3a'."*
Dependencies used:

```
<PackageReference Include="Firebase.Auth" Version="1.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="FirebaseDatabase.net" Version="4.0.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore3" Version="1.55.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Google.Cloud.Firestore" Version="2.4.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" Version="5.2.7" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="5.0.10" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="5.0.2" />
```

I tried adding Google.Apis, Google.Apis.Auth, Google.Apis.Auth.Mvc, Google.Apis.Core, result was the same.

Small code with this exception:
AuthCallbackController.cs

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc.Controllers
{
    public class AuthCallbackController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
              return Redirect("/");
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace ToDo2019Help
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace ToDo2019Help
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

There is more code in the final project, but the same exception is still thrown on *app.UseEndpoints*. i'm sorry for bad english. Thank you for any help!

**EDIT**

If replaced in AuthCallbackController.cs

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

with line

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
```

this exception is no longer thrown,
but **GetUserId** require **System.Web.Mvc.Controller** and **controller.Session** is
error "CS7069. Reference    The reference to the type "HttpSessionStateBase" requires its definition in "System.Web", but it could not be found"

AppFlowMetadata.cs

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows;

public class AppFlowMetadata : Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc.FlowMetadata
{
    private static readonly IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
           new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
           {
               ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
               {
                   ClientId = "PPPPPPPP",
                   ClientSecret = "PPPPPPPPP"
               },
               Scopes = new[] { "email", "profile" },
           });

    public override string GetUserId(System.Web.Mvc.Controller controller)
    {
                var user = controller.Session["user"];
                if (user == null)
                {
                    user = System.Guid.NewGuid();
                    controller.Session["user"] = user;
                }
                return user.ToString();
                throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override string AuthCallback
    {
        get
        {
            return @"/AuthCallback/IndexAsync";
        }
    }

    public override IAuthorizationCodeFlow Flow
    {
        get { return flow; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add reference to System.Web.HttpContextBase

Comment: great thanks! I think I understood what the mistake was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake was using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows in a **.Net Core** project. 
You need to use the Google.Apis.Auth.**AspNetCore3** library. [An example of how to use it](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-core-3)